# Why does this error pop up while working with Deep Q learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I have been working with Deep Q Learning on Windows 10 Machine. I have version 0.4.1 of pytorch with NVIDA graphics card.

```
def select_action(self, state):
    probs = F.softmax(self.model(Variable(state, volatile = True))*7)
    action = probs.multinomial()
    return action.data[0,0]
```

From this section of the code, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: multinomial() missing 1 required positional arguments: "num_samples"
```

If any other information is needed, It will be very quickly provided.

Comment: Hello , welcome to SO. I actually have no experience in this. From the question and the details it seems like you have a parameter missing though. perhaps check the doc for the needed arguments ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html) you didn't specify the `num_samples` of `multinomial` function to draw your multinomial distribution.

> **torch.multinomial(input, num_samples, replacement=False, out=None)**
>
> > Returns a tensor where each row contains **num_samples**
> >     indices sampled from the multinomial probability distribution located
> >     in the corresponding row of tensor **input**.

Change the code as below:

```
def select_action(self, state):
    probs = F.softmax(self.model(Variable(state, volatile = True))*7)
    action = probs.multinomial(1) # 1 is the number of samples to draw
    return action.data[0,0]
```